# Meteor.js onRendered & rendered

Tags: meteor

As of recently all documentation of meteor states that `onRendered` is a new way to get a callback when template has finished rendering. and `rendered` is just for backwards compatibility.

However, that just does not seem to work for me. `onRendered` never gets executed, while `rendered` does. I have newest meteor version 1.1.0.2

```
//only this is executed
Template.hello.rendered = function(){
  console.log('rendered');
}

//and this is not
Template.hello.onRendered = function(){
  console.log('onRendered');
}
//even if I comment first one out
```

and both functions in action you can see in this github [repo](https://github.com/martunta/metRendered). 
Am I doing something wrong, or this is a defect in onRendered?

and second question - reason why I started to dig into this - how can I execute code every time an dom element is added/removed to my template? `rendered` does not seem to get called when that happens. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[onRendered](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered) takes a function as an **argument**. Try this instead:

```js
Template.hello.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('onRendered');
});
```

With that change, you should find both `rendered` and `onRendered` will be called. Also note that you can now add multiple `onRendered` callbacks for a given template.

Comment: will try in a moment. And second question?

Comment: @MartinsUntals you can use a nested template containing the dom that is removed and added with an onRendered callback on it. Or you can use the  ui hooks if you're trying to get an animation going (demo: https://github.com/RainHaven/meteor-ui-hooks-demo/blob/master/simple-todos.js#L45-L62)

Comment: you should improve that link

Comment: @brainmurphy1 I updated the link from the latest blaze docs. With the migration of blaze to its own project, there are going to be a lot of broken links in people's answers.

Comment: Great job. I didn't realize it was a broken link. It looked intentional since it directed to the api docs.